# PostgreSQL Interface error "connection already closed" using module psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have below lambda function to connect to PostgreSQL database. I am able to execute the query only once , second time when it executes , it gives Interface Error as below.

## Error

```
{   "errorMessage": "cursor already closed",   "errorType": "InterfaceError",   "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/my_lambda.py\", line 30, in handler\n    cursor.execute(query)\n"   ] }
```

## Function Log

```
START RequestId: e2a1d17e-48e5-4fa8-bd43-80a27658491a Version: $LATEST
[ERROR] InterfaceError: cursor already closed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/my_lambda.py", line 30, in handler
    cursor.execute(query)
END RequestId: e2a1d17e-48e5-4fa8-bd43-80a27658491a
```

## Lambda Function Code

```
import sys
import logging
import psycopg2
import json
import os

# rds settings
rds_host  = os.environ.get('RDS_HOST')
rds_username = os.environ.get('RDS_USERNAME')
rds_user_pwd = os.environ.get('RDS_USER_PWD')
rds_db_name = os.environ.get('RDS_DB_NAME')

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

try:
    conn_string = "host=%s user=%s password=%s dbname=%s" % \
                    (rds_host, rds_username, rds_user_pwd, rds_db_name)
    conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
except:
    logger.error("ERROR: Could not connect to Postgres instance.")
    sys.exit()

logger.info("SUCCESS: Connection to RDS Postgres instance succeeded")

def handler(event, context):

    query = "select count(*) as active_sessions from pg_stat_activity where state = 'active' AND pid <> pg_backend_pid() and state <> 'idle'"
    cursor.execute(query)
    results = cursor.fetchone()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
    print(results)
```

I have tried using other queries as well and it gives me the same error.

Comment: No surprise if you commit after closing everything.

Comment: @Klaus D, i am sorry i pasted the wrong code, i already tried removing it , but it executes the first time and second time it gives the error. i have updated Code.

Comment: Have you tried to move the `try` block in `def handler(event, context)`

Comment: Something to consider when moving the code that connects to the database into your handler is that your Lambda will run slower as it will not be able to reuse existing db connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment mentioned by @Philippe resolved the issue.

```
move the try block in def handler(event, context)
```